# How to persist data in react component from re-render?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, callback, axios, react-component

I'm making a simple axios call to the nodejs server from react to fetch products from mongoose schema model. When I first load the page, I used componentDidMount to fetch existing products from MongoDB. However, when I refresh the page, all the items are gone.

React Component (componentDidMount):

```
class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { products: '' };
  }

componentDidMount() {

  axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getProduct')
    .then(res => {
       this.setState({ products: res.data });
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Nodejs Server (/getProduct api):

```
app.get('/getProduct', (req,res) => {

   Products.find(product_id), (err, products) => {
       if(err) throw err;
       res.status(200).send(products);
   });
}
```

I believe this has something to do with callbacks? Please help, I'm new to react.

Comment: are you creating component inside componentDidMount?

Comment: sorry; typo. fixed

Comment: @jche if you want to save permanently then can use localstorage or sessionStorage because every time after reloading page api will be called.

Comment: sorry, i mean refresh the page, not reload.

Comment: here is proper way to save and fetch data from localStorage https://stackoverflow.com/a/58620458/6544460.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with small react application (without redux) then you have to use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to persist the data. Look at the below example.

```
class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // get product list from localstorage
    this.state = { products: localStorage.getItem('productList') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('productList')) : [] };
  }

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getProduct')
    .then(res => {
       this.setState({ products: res.data }, ()=>{
            // set product list in localstorage
            localStorage.setItem('productList', JSON.stringify(res.data));
         });
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}
```

Comment: Since you're using `axios` w/c auto transforms to JSON, you need to `stringify` the data before storing it and `parse` it to JSON when `get`ting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Product extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // get product list from localstorage
    this.state = {
      products: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products")) || []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/getProduct") // https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ products: res.data }, () => {
          // set product list in localstorage
          localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(res.data));
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { products } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {products
          ? products.map(product => <div key={product.id}>{product.title}</div>)
          : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```